# Isn't `-no-plt` always preferrable to `-z now`?

Tags: linker, elf, loader

I know that keeping the GOT writable in an ELF program throughout execution is a glaring attack surface and understand that it was decided to [avoid it by defaulting to `-z relro` and sometimes `-z now`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62527697/89706) (at the compiler level? Distro level? Not sure).

What I don't understand is why do we still bother erecting the elaborate PLT structure to prepare for lazy binding, then populate it entirely at load time. Wouldn't it have been better to default to `-no-plt`?  Is there some tradeoff I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is `-fno-plt` is not used by default in GCC because it disables any possibility of lazy binding.

Not keeping it the default lets the developer explicitly and knowingly choose it as an option if required.

Even if the link time option of `-z relro` and `-z now` are used, one can still use the environment variable `LD_BIND_NOT` at run time to modify the behaviour of `ld.so`. This is useful, [as documented here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), for use in conjunction with `LD_DEBUG` for debugging and trouble shooting. But that works **only if the PLT entries are still around**.

Also, there is a reference [here](https://maskray.me/blog/2021-01-18-gnu-indirect-function) of GNU Indirect Functions needing the PLT for their reasonable operation. Without the PLT, GNU Indirect Functions [require TEXTRELs](https://reviews.llvm.org/D61613) which is considered retrograde. In fact, [the answers to this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2172/why-are-got-and-plt-still-present-in-linux-static-stripped-binaries) explain why GOT and PLT are retained even in statically linked binaries. GNU Indirect Functions are [used in glibc](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/GNU_IFUNC), for instance, for enhanced runtime performance optimizations.

The PLT does have a bunch of uses, for which it is may be preferred, not to be kicked out by default. Even if it is not used, having the PLT entries around does have its advantages.

[This link](https://lists.alpinelinux.org/%7Ealpine/devel/%3C1628515011.zujvcn248v.none%40localhost%3E) has some discussion of different platforms including support for `-fno-plt` and some making it the default with benefits and downsides mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! Some personal thoughts: I find it hard to believe that people chose to leave a feature on for the rare case someone would use it for debugging.  Regarding performance:  the apple discussion MaskRay links to says "Mach-O has a .symbol_resolver feature which we regret adding because it adds per-call overheads that make it slower than just switching yourself in typical code patterns.". MaskRay's post's final paragraph suggests that `ifunc`s design in general is inferior to manual branching.    Finally, the alpine mailing list item is great and does make a good point about a size tradeoff.

Comment: @OfekShilon - I agree with the general observations you have made. But regarding the debugging scenario, trouble shooting times are specifically the times when one expects some support from the system. :-) If that's when I realize that gcc chucked out the PLT by default, I m likely to be unhappy. On the other hand if as a developer I am making that conscious choice by explicitly specifying -fno-plt then I would know that I am not allowed that help.